# Template parent class with no type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boost

On [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html) documentation, there is:

```
class times_two_visitor
    : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(int & i) const
    {
        i *= 2;
    }
    void operator()(std::string & str) const
    {
        str += str;
    }

};
```

What is the meaning of **boost::static_visitor<>** in the class declaration? 
It looks a like a template specialization but without any specific types. So I am very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template, class template as well as function template, using `<>` for template parameters if the template has default values of all the template parameters.

E.g.

```
template <typename T = int> struct Foo {};

Foo<double> f1;  // Explicitly specified template paramter
Foo<> f2;        // Default template parameter, int, is used.
```

---

```
template <typename T1 = int, typename T2 = double> struct Bar {};

Bar<float> b1;  // T1 = float, T2 = double
Bar<> b2;       // T1 = int, T2 = double
```

**PS**

I am surprised at the use of `boost::static_visitor<>` since [that class template](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/static_visitor.html) does not seem to have a default value of the template parameter.

Comment: There is a default parameter for the template type in the [header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp)

Comment: @DuffyChan, thanks for the info. It unfortunate that the header file and the documentation don't match.